# Arraylist, with if else statements

Tags: arraylist

I have a rather simple java programming question

i am currently working on an early stage assignment in java.

I need to make an Arraylist of Assistans (int salary, String name)

the tricky part, is that i need to make a method that states that you can only add the assistants if their salary is equal too or more than 150.

we want the method to work, no matter how many assistants we have.

so to sum up,

if the assistants salary is higher or equal to 150 we want them added,

else we dont want them added to the arraylist

any help is much appreciated :)

thanks in advance

Comment: please post your code, show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void AddAssitant(Assistant assistant, ArrayList list)
{
     if(assistant.Salary >= 150)
     {
        list.Add(assistant);
     }

}
```